# Display div or input box, when drop down value selected as Others

Tags: html, angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel

Plnkr code for review : https://plnkr.co/edit/vWR7kK9MQw4nyciRt1Bj?p=preview

How do I display a div or input box, once a drop down value is selected as Others?

**Html**

```
<div class="form-group fields col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
    <label>EDUCATION QUALIFICATION *</label>
    <select name="education" class="form-control1 drop" required ng-model="model.education" placeholder="select">
        <option value='' disabled selected>Select</option>
        <option value="male">10th</option>
        <option value="female">12th</option>
        <option value="male">Graduate</option>
        <option value="male">Post Graduate</option>
        <option value="male">Ph.d</option>
        <option value="other">Others</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group fields col-sm-2 col-xs-4 floatField" ng-if =" model.education=Others;displayDiv = true">  
    <label>OTHERS</label>
    <input type="text" name="othereducation" class="form-control1" autocomplete="off" ng-model="model.othereducation"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you manually writing option tags instead of using ng-options?

Comment: Just for practise purpose.

Comment: You want to display textbox or div based on the select box value?

Comment: you can use model (model.education) to show/hide input box. aren't you?

Comment: @ram1993 I tried that giving ng-show ="model.education==others" still it has not displaying.

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon plunker you provided not working properly(no angular). Can you please provide demo. One thing i noticed for Others option value is male.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Angular in-built directives ng-show/ng-hide to show or hide the content.

So you can add the below snippet to show the required content when you select the value 'other' in selectbox.

```
<div ng-show="model.education==='other'">
    DIV/input you want to show
</div>
```

**Demo:**
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vocabuz/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Can you quickly replicate the issue in jsbin?

Comment: For me it is working. see the updated answer with demo

Comment: Check for the error you are getting in your browser console

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/vWR7kK9MQw4nyciRt1Bj?p=preview  No errors. But you can see the code here

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon There are lot of changes you need to in your plnkr. You didn't include AnagularJS, specified ng-app and how do you think you are running angular application?

Comment: Hello, ng-app I given in my original index.html , I have this file in my view folder  actually.Those things I handled already,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/eTikkgPG4YlDZfkjTlBo?p=preview)

Try the code below

**Code**

```
<div  ng-if="model.education==='other'">
         <label >OTHERS</label>
             <input type="text" name="othereducation" class="form-control1" autocomplete="off" ng-model="model.othereducation"/>

          </div>
```

Comment: HI its not working. I already tried https://plnkr.co/edit/vWR7kK9MQw4nyciRt1Bj?p=preview